# qooxdoo : Show FPS on screen ?

Tags: qooxdoo

Simple question : How to show Frame Per Second ( fps ) on screen , e.g. on a `qx.ui.basic.Label` ?

Further question, how to limit FPS to 30 ?

Note: I'm using qx.Desktop .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qooxdoo does not offer such a functionality. You can try to calculate the FPS yourself but I would not trust on that because the measurement could influence the frame rate. I use the fps counter on chrome for that:

http://www.mobitechie.com/browser/how-to-enable-fps-counter-on-chrome-brower/